# Run Python in Android Terminal

Tags: android, shell, python-2.7

I have a Android 5.1 CM12 (rooted, supersu, busybox) and try to access Python For Android (PythonForAndroid_r5.apk) by Android Terminal.

I have followed this Tutorial:
http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.de/2015/01/installing-python-on-android-50.html

this is the script I use (python2):

```
    export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard

    PYTHONPATH=${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python
    PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
    export PYTHONPATH
    export TEMP=${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python/tmp
    export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP
    export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib
/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python "$@"
```

python2 and sh are located in system/bin/

but when I execute these script I get:

```
C:\Users\bla>adb shell python2
: not found/python2[2]:
: is not an identifier: export: PYTHONPATH
```

What tell me this error! And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have played around for a while and finally I got it work.
my script (python2 located in system/bin):

```
export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
export PYTHONPATH=/mnt/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6
export TEMP=/mnt/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python/tmp
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$TEMP
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib:/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:/mnt/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python
/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python/bin/python "$@"
```

On Android Terminal:

```
u0_a101@C1905:/ $ su
root@C1905:/ # python2
```

Now it work to include Python2.7 in Android 5.1 Terminal!

```
dlopen libpython2.6.so
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Mar 20 2011, 16:54:21)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux-armv7l
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print ";)"
;)
>>> exit()
root@C1905:/ #
```

hope it help someone